# Error in sencha architect localization(Extjs 5)

Tags: extjs5

Am very new to sencha architect. I need to do localization in sencha architect. Using extjs 5, I refer http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/localization.html document.

And trying without Sencha Cmd.

Getting error as localhost/projectname/js/pt_BR.js file not found. Not able to get any working examples.

ext-all and ext-locale-es if any updating as mentioned above inindex.html. Its not able to fetch js from the path. so i gave exact path location for both js files.

Please let me know whats the mistake am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got It

1. Add "requires": ["ext-locale"] in app.json in created project file.
2. Add the preferred language "locale": "es" in app.json out side requires
3. Should not preview the project. Need to create a build. Click build web app in tool bar.Before that click build setting and set the path to save the files. Once clicking buil web app. App will be builded in specified path.
4. All the default stings will be changed to mentioned language. (In app.json we mentioned "locale": "es" spanish language.)

default strings like ok button, date picker, etc. Labels will not be updated with app.json language we need to add labels plugin.

Comment: Maybe worth explaining how Sencha architect handles app.json. If the file needs to be changed manually, do we have any guarantee that the architect will not overwrite it?

Comment: 1.  As i told am new to sencha architect, even am not aware of sencha   touch. But what i understood is like, when creating a new project in sencha architect. Its creating app.json along with the package with default key-value such as app Name, launching file, initialize file, sass, ext libs, bootstrap, etc.

Comment: 2. While previewing or building the application, app.json will not be override. It will work some thing similar to package.json in nodejs.